# No Steam Log-In on other sites

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, user-accounts, steam

*Before we begin, I'm sorry if this is posted somewhere inappropriately.*

When I first joined Stack Exchange ***(via Arqade)*** I was given the option of using Steam to sign in. When I attempted to sign in to another Stack Exchange website (specifically The **Board/Card Game** site) I was not given the option to log in using Steam; my other credentials *(Username/Password)* didn't seem to accepted either, *but that's probably not important to this question.*

My point is, could a log-in via Steam "button" be used with the other Stack Exchange websites, or would it be too far a stretch? (It would at least be acceptable on The **Board/Card Game** site, I should think?)

Comment: Relevant MSO:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152916/steam-login-button-is-missing-from-sites-other-than-arqade

Comment: Also relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150191/i-use-steam-to-log-in-how-do-i-use-this-logon-for-stackoverflow-com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a workaround, you can use Steam's OpenID by clicking "Show more login options" and entering `http://steamcommunity.com/openid` in the box provided.

[image: screenshot]

But it could definitely be added on the list as Steam is huge among gamers. Maybe to the smaller buttons, which are shown when you click for more login options.

Comment: Thanks for the OpenID bit; I was unaware of that. Also, I do agree the smaller buttons area would be good for less gaming related websites.

Answer (score 3):

### Open ID Support ended in 2018

It is no longer possible to log in with Steam's Open ID on Arqade or the wider SE network.

See the following Meta SE Post: [Support for OpenID ended on July 25, 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307647/179041)

Answer (score -1):

This paragraph from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150192/203444) seems to be to be another work-around:

> Alternatively, you can associate another OpenID account with your account on this site by going to your user page and clicking "my logins" at the top. Then you should be able to click "add more logins..." to associate another account with this one. Then you can use that account to log in to stackoverflow.

Comment: I believe the hesitation is not wanting to cross-pollinate, so to speak. I don't want personality X (the stuff I do on SE/Arqade/etc.) to be muddled with personality Y (one of my Google accounts, or my Facebook, or whatever).